# prometheus_python instrumentation - Bucketing in histogram

Tags: python, prometheus

I am trying to instrument API health using python-prometheus lib. I was using prometheus histogram for API response times as directed in [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/6abff162d92a8c11e24b56a084bac1958d42c0d9/prometheus_client/core.py#L823) and doing a http export of metrics

**Expected behaviour**

I went through the bucketing logic in the [code](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/6abff162d92a8c11e24b56a084bac1958d42c0d9/prometheus_client/core.py#L864) I am expecting a histogram of pre-set buckets of response times. I defined buckets for 1,3,5,10,Inf (greater than 10s) (i.e, less than or equal to 1s/3s/5s)

So if I there is only **one** request that took 2s, the 3s bucket will have a frequency of 1 and other buckets are zero.

**Code Snippet on bucketing**

```
def observe(self, amount):
        '''Observe the given amount.'''
        self._sum.inc(amount)
        for i, bound in enumerate(self._upper_bounds):
            if amount <= bound:
                self._buckets[i].inc(1)
                break
```

I think break ensures bucketing happens only once for an instance.

Response times:

*Before*

[image]

*After*

[image]

For a sample request that took 3.1s if we could subtract the latency sum from before and after,

5s , 10s and Inf buckets are getting updated too. I am looking to find where and how buckets >= 3.1s are getting updated.

Other Details:

python - prometheus is used on multiprocess mode

Version Info:

1. Python - 2.7
2. prometheus_client [Python] - 0.0.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `le` stands for less than or equal to, so this is the expected behaviour. The `histogram_quantile` function handles this automatically, so you shouldn't need to worry about this implementation detail.

This reason it is this way is so that if a histogram has too many buckets, you can safely drop some them on the ingestion side.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @brian-brazil. If we look a bit deeply into the code, it looks to be each entry appears to be bucketed only once. let me try to update the question with code snippet.

Comment: I understand the behaviour is "le" so it is working as expected. I am curious as to which code does that part. One I am highlighting, fills only one bucket.